# How to search a line contains N target characters/patterns in vim?

Tags: vim

Today I need to search if which lines contains 4 single-quote `'`.

But `g/'\{4,4\}` can only catch four continuous single-quote.

So I make my code into something like `:g/\[^'\]\?'\[^'\]\?'\[^'\]\?'\[^'\]\?'\[^'\]\?`.

Which doesn't work and looks ugly.

Is there a beautiful way, or at least a workable way to search a line which target pattern has appeared Nth times in it?

Or better, we can specify the minimum pattern appeared times and maximum pattern appeared times?

Comment: May be `\('.*\)\{4\}` ?

Comment: A question, why this `.*` won't include single-quote `'`, the `( )` makes it non greedy?

Comment: @Zen it's still greedy. (Check on a line with 5 quotes).

Comment: "greedy" mean "maximum **in possible**", so if you have 5 or 6 quotes in line the pattern will match all 5 or 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do:

```
/^[^']*\%('[^']*\)\{4}$
```

It searches for a quote followed by any non-quotes (`'[^']`) four times (`\{4}`; here, you can also specify ranges like `\{2,5}`). To ensure that the exact number matches in the line, the pattern is *anchored* to start (`^[^']*`, with optional non-quotes in front) and end (`$`, trailing non-quotes already included in the repetition).

Comment: What does the % do here, didn't see this symbol much in regex.

Comment: That's like `\(`; it just avoids capturing (which is not needed here).